# When using git and GitHub,in the case of a corrupted repository, is it possible to go back with a clean version in GitHub?

Tags: git, github, version-control

When using git and GitHub, in the case of a corrupted repository, if we have locally a previous clean backup of the repository, is it possible to go back with a clean version in GitHub?

Let's say we have locally, this folder: /home/toto/.

In /home/toto/ there is the working directory and the .git folder, with the repository.

This project is tracked on GitHub, say in user/ toto.

In user/toto, we find, as usual, issues, pull requests, wiki, etc. for the user/toto repository.

Now, if /home/toto/ is corrupted, and it has been pushed into GitHub, and we have a clean saved version  of /home/toto/. I guess we can go back like this:

- delete the user/toto repository in GitHub.
- create a new empty user/toto in GitHub.
- push the uncorrupted /home/toto/ to user/toto in GitHub.

I did some tests, and it seems working fine.

BUT! in this case we lost all the issues, pull requests, etc......

Is it possible to save all this meta-information,  from the [REST GitHub API](https://api.github.com/) or with other idea!,  before deleting the corrupted user/toto in GitHub, and then injecting this meta-information afterwards?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You also tried to do a forced push? Try this command with your clean working copy you want to have on github. Just do it for the one or every branch which got corrupted:

```
git push --force
```

All your repository metadata will then stay and your code basically switch to a your clean state of your backup again.

In case you have protected branches, go to your repo settings and unprotect the branch you want to overwrite. Then again try to execute the command.

Hope this helps. Feel free to ask any further questions. I am feeling that this will be the easiest way solving your problem.

Comment: That sounds good! But because I don't want to make the mess a second time: By using --force, I completely exchange the current repository on the remote server by the current local repository ?

Comment: == totally delete the current repository on the remote server and push the current local repository ? For example, if I make a local clone of a repository on a remote server, that contains 10 commits, let's say locRepository_10 and that I do, in local,  5 more commits, then I push on the remote server, then again I make again a local clone, let' say locRepository_15. If now I go to the locRepository_10 folder and I do a git push --force, it will be now the remote repository without trace of the 5 more commits ?

Comment: "By using --force, I completely exchange the current repository on the remote server by the current local repository"
You are not exchanging the whole repository, you are only forcing the push of one specific branch which you checked out. I would start with your masters branch of your back up. 
1. Navigate to your BackUp and call `git checkout master`
2. Do the forced push: `git push --force`. Your remote repository master branch contains then only the history of your BackUps master branch
3. When you have history (commits) not merged in your Backup, then also push these branches to GitHub

Comment: Yes you are totally right, that your GitHub then would be without the trace of your 5 more commits in your example.
But I thought this is your use case. What you can also do is to revert your locRepository_15 to one special commit where your repo got corrupted, let's say to commit 13. Then you are doing the forced push, then only the trace of 2 commits would be lost

Comment: My problem is not to only rool back to an previous commit. I rewrited the history and it gave problems with, at least, meta data (issues, etc ...). So I want to totally replace the history with the backup !!! Ok I will try with --force.

Comment: Thank you Thorben. It seems that all are fine now !